# Python: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (101) (2)

Tags: python, numpy

I get the following error message when I run the code shown below: *'ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (101) (2) '*

The full message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Bob/Desktop/MachineLearning/machLearn.py", line 47, in <module>
    ppn.fit(X,y)
  File "/Users/Bob/Desktop/MachineLearning/machLearn.py", line 18, in fit
    self.w_[1:] += update * xi
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (101) (2) 
[Finished in 0.8s with exit code 1]
```

The error happens when I run the last line of code (ie. the second plt.show()) The first plt.show() works fine.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Perception(object):
    def __init__(self, eta=0.01, n_iter=10):
        self.eta  = eta
        self.n_iter = n_iter

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.w_ = np.zeros(1 + X.shape[1])
        self.errors_ = []

        for _ in range(self.n_iter):
            errors = 0
            for xi, target in zip(X, y):
                update = self.eta * (target - self.predict(xi))
                self.w_[1:] += update * xi
                self.w_[0] += update
                errors += int(update != 0.0)
            self.errors_.append(errors)
        return self

    def net_input(self, X):
        return np.dot(X, self.w_[1:]) + self.w_[0]

    def predict(self,x):
        return np.where(self.net_input(X) >0.0, 1, -1)

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book/master/code/datasets/iris/iris.data',header=None)
y = df.iloc[0:100, 4].values
y = np.where(y == 'Iris-setosa',-1,1)
X = df.loc[0:100,[0,2]].values

plt.scatter(X[:50, 0], X[:50, 1],
    color='red', marker='o', label='setosa') 
plt.scatter(X[50:100, 0], X[50:100, 1],
    color='blue', marker='x', label='versicolor')

plt.xlabel('sepal length')
plt.ylabel('petal length')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()

ppn = Perception(eta=0.1, n_iter=10)
ppn.fit(X,y)
plt.plot(range(1, len(ppn.errors_) +1), ppn.errors_, marker='o')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Number of misclassifications')
plt.show()
```

NB: The above code example is from from Python Machine Learning (Sebastian Raschka, 2015, pg.26)

Comment: One of these 3 items `self.w_[1:], update, xi` has shape (101,) and the other is (2,) - i.e. 101 items in one, 2 in the other.  Which number(s) make sense?  You may need to verify that.

Answer (score 0):

`self.w_[1:]` has size `X.shape[1]`, which I assume is `102`, while `xi` will have size `X.shape[0]`, which I think is `2`.

You probably want to change this line:

```
for xi, target in zip(X, y):
```

to

```
for xi, target in zip(X.T, y):
```

which will give `xi` size `X.shape[1]` to match `self.w_[1:]`